# How to run a tensorflow operation between each step of estimator.train

Tags: tensorflow

I am using estimators to train my models.

I have some operations in the graph that update some of the non-trainable variables.

How can I run these ops using hooks in estimator.train function

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow.python.training import training

class MySessionRunHook(training.SessionRunHook):
  # your hook definition here

  def __init__():
    # ...

  def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    # Get your ops
    your_ops = ...
    run_context.session.run(your_ops)

hook = MySessionRunHook(...)
estimator.train(train_input_fn, hooks=[hook])
```